# Angular Material tool-tip with HTML support

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I just want to know that, Is there any good third party `angular material tool-tip plugin` with the support of `HTML`?

I am using `Material design` with `Angular 7` only(no bootstrap)

Although I am using [ng2-tooltip-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive) and it full fill's all my needs but it has some issues related to positioning of tool-tip on different browsers.

Any other suggestions as

> HTML is not supported in angular material tooltips and for now, they
>   don't have intentions to support it either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used SAT Popover for styling tooltips. You can give it an angular component and it will display as you style it.

https://ncstate-sat.github.io/popover/

Comment: What about its cross browser compatibility?

Comment: It´s working on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge. I didn´t test it on IE.