# How to adjust Mat Tooltip position to center of the screen?

Tags: html, css, angular, tooltip

I have a mat tooltip **for a table element** on a page that is embedded in an iframe on a page. When I want to see the tooltip, if the text is long, a tooltip is exceeding the limits of the frame.
[image]

And the position is adjusted as "after":

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="budgetGroupName">
          <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="20%">Budget Group</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell matTooltip="{{payroll.budgetGroupName}}" matTooltipPosition="after" *cdkCellDef="let payroll"
                    fxFlex="20%"><div class="wrapped-text">{{payroll.budgetGroupName}}</div></mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

I tried "right", "above" as well but they are also going to outside of frame. Can I adjust it to for example "center of the screen" or smth else to see more clearly? Or I need to use only this 6 different option for positioning like right,left-above, belove, after, before or can I adjust manually to middle of the screen ?

Or, if it is possible, if there is a function to put a scroll on tooltip text, i can use it as well to see the full content

Comment: Have you tried to set your own CSS style for that matTooltip ? Something like ::ng-deep { .mat-tooltip { position: absolute; top: 0; // width...height..and so on... } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the problem i am facing last month using `mat-tooltip` as it didn't allow any `HTML` support so i came up with the solution which works perfectly in all case and also fully customize-able. 
[sat-popover](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ncstate/sat-popover)

```
<button [satPopoverAnchor]='popover' (click)="popover.toggle()">
  See Contact Details
</button>

<sat-popover #popover hasBackdrop>
  <app-contact-overview [contact]="myContact"></app-contact-overview>
</sat-popover>
```

I also try [ng2-tooltip-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive) but it some time show `tooltip` on random position so i prefer using `sat-popover` over it.

I also post that question on `stack-overflow` [angular-material-tool-tip-with-html-support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316885/angular-material-tool-tip-with-html-support)

Answer (score -1):

<sat-popover verticalAlign="below” hasBackdrop forceAlignment />